# Cloudsight Api provides empty response on image Upload on Android platform

Tags: android, cloudsight

I am trying to upload an image on *"https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests"*
but after request call i am getting all the fields null into response .i.e status,name,token etc. I am using retrofit 2.0.1 for making request call.

**Code**:

```
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

MultipartBody.Part body =
MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image_request[image]", file.getName(), requestFile);

String descriptionString = "en-US";
RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), descriptionString);

**API CALL:**
@Multipart
    @POST("https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests")
    Call<FileUploadResponse> uploadPhoto(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorisation,
            @Part("image_request[locale]") RequestBody description,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

I am getting all the fields into response.body null. Please help.

Comment: Getting following 

When try to send MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data") :
{"error":{"image":["at least one of image or remote_image_url must be set","You are not allowed to upload multipart/form-data files"]}}  

When try to send MediaType.parse("image/*") :
{"error":{"image":["at least one of image or remote_image_url must be set","You are not allowed to upload image/* files"]}}

Comment: CloudSight replied me as following:
*body's* content type should be the mime type of the image file (image/jpg, image/png, etc Instead of MultipartBody.Part ??. Anybody knows how to convert it?  I am using Retrofit 2.0.1 . Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Upload image file like this:

```
File file = // initialize file here

MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));

Call<MyResponse> call = api.uploadPhoto(filePart);//u can send other parameters along with the filePart depending upon ur method signature
```

Comment: RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image_request[image]", file.getName(), requestFile);

Answer (score 0):

CloudSight stopped accepting MultipartBody.Part So we have to send RequestBody i.e file with image name.

I have solved the issue with following steps:

```
RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image*/"), file);

String descriptionString = "en-US";

RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), descriptionString);

apiInterface.uploadPhoto("CloudSight key",description, requestFile);


In retrofit api call:

@Multipart
    @POST("https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests")
    Call<FileUploadResponse> uploadPhoto(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorisation,
            @Part("image_request[locale]") RequestBody description,
            @Part("image_request[image]\"; filename=\"file.jpg\" " ) RequestBody file);
```

Hope This helps. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddler/postman request? I can't make it work